# How to apply recursively chmod directories without affecting files?

Tags: shell, find, chmod

After I apply `chmod -R` to a directory, permissions are changed for everything within (files and directories). How can I add execute/search (`x`) permissions to directories without modifying the files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use *find*.

```
find ./ -type d -execdir chmod 750 {} +
```

Where 750 is the mode you'd like to apply and "./" is the directory you will recursively search.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Gilles and *find(1)*, I've revised this for additional security and performance.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, it isn't too frequent that I learn something new about Unix tools :-) That is awesome.  Also, now reading the *find* documentation, one should really use -execdir instead.

Answer (score 10):

In this particular case you can use `X` instead of `x` which only adds the bits to directories or files which already have the executable bit set for some user (i.e. `chmod -R +X my_dir`).

In general (e.g. if you wanted to make all directories readable without affecting the files), you could either use `find` with `-type d` or if you're using zsh (or bash 4 with `shopt -s globstar`) the `**/` glob (both without passing the `-R` flag to `chmod`).

Comment: @Gilles: Good point, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: "use X instead of x which only adds the bits to directories or files which already have the executable bit set for some user" - Thanks! I've missed this thing a lot!