# execute bit on directories, but not files

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply recursively chmod directories without affecting files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/how-to-apply-recursively-chmod-directories-without-affecting-files)

What is the command to apply execute permission for directories (for traversal), but leave the execute bit off for files contained in the directory?

Comment: There are a lot of questions that deal with this already: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24662/chmod-r-644-documents http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/i-accidentally-chmod-r-x-on-a-directory-how-do-i-restore-the-correct-permissi http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/recursively-change-file-permission-but-not-directories, ...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the executable bit from existing files you can use the `X` mode. To recursively set the executable bit on all directories use:

```
chmod -R a+X dir
```

From man chmod:

> execute/search only if the file is  a  directory or  already  has 
>   execute permission for some user (X)

Answer (score 4):

You want to test this first (as I didn't):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

Find all directories, then add x-bit for the owner/user.

Comment: If I understand the `chmod` man page correctly, Ulrich's answer is the better one.

Comment: The problem with Ulrich's solution is that to have to specify the directory. The solution by @jippie can be used as a wildcard change.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I wanted to change only all directories (not files)